# EF adding parent and child collection in one call of SaveChanges

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have this code which adds a parent model `AssetModel` with a child model `AssetModelInputs`

my `AssetModel` looks like this

```
public class AssetModel : BaseModel
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int AssetId { get; set; }
    public Asset Asset { get; set; }
    public int ModelId { get; set; }
    public Model Model { get; set; }

    public ICollection<AssetModelInput> AssetModelInputs { get; set; }
}
```

and the `AssetModelInputs` look like this

```
public class AssetModelInput : BaseModel
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int AssetModelId { get; set; }
    public AssetModel AssetModel { get; set; }
    public int ModelInputId { get; set; }
    public ModelInput ModelInput { get; set; }
    public int? DataStreamId { get; set; }
    public DataStream DataStream { get; set; }
}
```

my api method look like this.

```
var record = _mapper.Map(data, new AssetModel());
context.AssetModels.Add(record);
await context.SaveChangesAsync(cancellation);
```

where `data` is an `AssetModelCreateInput` which is just

```
public record AssetModelCreateInput(
    int AssetId,
    int ModelId,
    List<AssetModelInputCreateInput>? AssetModelInputs
);

public record AssetModelInputCreateInput(
    int? AssetModelId, // this is the foreign key id to AssetModel, this can be remove since it is always null
    int ModelInputId,
    int? DataStreamId
);
```

now when I automap the value of `AssetModelId` will always be 0 since the data is not yet inserted in the database so when I run the saving part it will throw the error of

> {"23505: duplicate key value violates unique constraint "PK_AssetModelInputs""}

this is because the id is still 0.

Now, how I can make it work considering I only want to save it in one go (single `SaveChanges`). I know I can fix it but calling the SaveChanges twice by excluding the `AssetModelInputs` in the auto mapper and assign the id of the parent model on the child model after inserting.

anyone has an idea how to fix this?

Comment: this looks similar to this but I cannot find the solution https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52615106/entity-framework-inserting-a-parent-and-child-model-with-fk-simultaneously

Comment: How can `PK_AssetModelInputs` be violated by values of `AssetModelId`?